# bazaar auto tag

Tags: bazaar

I want to use the automatic_tag_name hook to automatic create tag name without the need of manually typing

I tried to write it like it :  automatic_tag_name(branch name,10)= "GIL"

1. Is it the correct syntax? (i found iittle information on it in the documents)
2. Is it possible to create tag name from a file? this file will contains only the tag name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example pahe here:
http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/latest/en/user-guide/hooks.html

SO correct call should be:

```
def post_push_autotag(push_result):
    automatic_tag_name(push_result.new_revno)

branch.Branch.hooks.install_named_hook('post_push_autotag', post_push_autotag, 'My autotag')
```

Comment: thanks @TridenT. i wasnt aware that i must write plugin to use the auto_tag hook. for my question #2 , i can solve it in the pluging also?

Comment: Yes, you can read the file, get the tag name and use it in the automatic_tag_name() function.